# How to display two digits after the decimal point on my template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have two questions 
How to display two digits after the decimal point on my template ?
and how to have the comma after my 3-digit number, for example if I have 156200, I display 156.200 in my template

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of the sheer lack of effort to find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can make it in views.py action and set it to your template
you can make some thing like that:-

```
from __future__ import division
num = 156200/1000
```

or make it with JavaScript in your templete